# convert value of a collection into a key in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

this my mysql query:

```
$tmp=almacen::select('nombre_empresa','oferta')->join('users','users.id','=','almacen.emp_id')->where('almacen.event_id','5')->get();
```

this returns several objects like these:

```
   ...
   App\almacen {#1948
     nombre_empresa: "Aux1",
     oferta: "Serv_1234",
   },
   App\almacen {#1947
     nombre_empresa: "Aux2",
     oferta: "Serv 12345678",
   },
  ...
```

i need to convert "nombre_empresa" in a key, for example

```
$tmp['Aux2']
this return:
"Serv 12345678"
```

Is it possible to do this in Laravel? or should I do it in another way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure Laravel can handle that, check out the [available collections methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections). `mapWithKeys` is probably what you're looking for:

```
$mapped = $results->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return [$item['nombre_empresa'] => $item['oferta']];
});
```

Edit: `mapWithKeys` rather than `map`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-mapwithkeys

Answer (score 9):

You can use [keyBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-keyby):

```
$tmp->keyBy('nombre_empresa');
```

You can chain it directly at the end of your query, after the get method.

But on this case you are only getting 2 fields from the database you can use `pluck` directly on the `query builder`:

```
$tmp=almacen::select('nombre_empresa','oferta')
    ->join('users','users.id','=','almacen.emp_id')
    ->where('almacen.event_id','5')
    ->pluck('oferta','nombre_empresa');
```

The second argument of pluck will be used for the key.
If none is given it will just use numeric keys: 0, 1,...

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, all solutions are valid, but the way I would do it which I think is also considered to be best practice in Laravel is by using `pluck()`
[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck)

Example:

```
$tmp=almacen::select('nombre_empresa','oferta')
    ->join('users','users.id','=','almacen.emp_id')
    ->where('almacen.event_id','5')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('oferta', 'nombre_empresa')
    ->toArray();
```

Do notice that `pluck()` is a new method introduced in version 5.2 to replace the before used `lists()`

- Notice that I would transform toArray() but it is not a must, I would consider it since with such a simple collection I might not need the extra functionality making this variable take up less space.